# Browser plugin to capture markup / DOM

Tags: web-development, web-browser

I have a need to capture snapshots of the DOM as I use a web application.  If I was using Chrome I could do this through a slow manual process stop what I was doing with the app, open the developer tools, select the elements tab, copy as HTML, paste into a new file.

With practice I could do this reasonably fast, but is there a plugin (or indeed a less well known browser) that can do this perhaps on a keystroke?

I am willing to use any browser (for Windows, Linux or OS X) that is reasonably compliant with modern standards and can execute JavaScript.

Comment: On which operating system(s) should this browser run?

Comment: @unor - my need has passed, but actually I didn't care what OS, I would have used Windows, Linux or OSX.